# What brand and model is Clara Oswald's motorbike?

Tags: doctor-who

Well, I'm thinking of getting a motorcycle for my birthday. Then I realized it might actually be cooler if I got Clara Oswald's bike.

Can anybody tell me what brand/model it is?

[image]

Comment: Looks suspiciously like a Truimph

Comment: Doctor Who is produced by the BBC, so please do remember that other brands of motorcycle are available.

Answer (score 20):

**A Triumph Bonneville Scrambler.**

You can make out the “Triumph” badge in the picture you’ve included, and a couple of sites have pinned down the exact model. I'm not a motorcycle expert, but I can look at the picture you've shown, and the pictures they have, and see that it's probably the same model:

- From [“The ten best and five worst Doctor Who bike connections” on motorcyclenews.com](http://www.motorcyclenews.com/mcn/news/newsresults/general-news/2012/december/dec2412-ten-best-doctor-who-connections/):

  > This year’s Christmas special *The Snowmen* (BBC 1, Christmas Day) features the Time Lord riding a bike, namely a Triumph Bonneville Scrambler, with new companion Jenna-Louise Coleman
  >
  > [image]
- From [“Doctor Who and Motorbikes” on Flying Monkey Gear](http://flyingmonkeymotogear.com/index.php/to-boldly-go/201-doctor-who-a-motorbikes):

  > If you are “Whovian” and up to date with the series, you may have taken notice to the top photos showing the current and Eleventh Doctor with a young female passenger atop a late model Triumph Bonneville Scrambler.
- From [“Suspend your disbelief: Doctor Who” on Ride Apart](https://rideapart.com/articles/suspend-your-disbelief-doctor-who):

  > As evidenced by the rubber knee pads and flat seat, these images from the set appear to show a Triumph Scrambler, the dirt-capable version of the Bonneville.

The first and second link identify a number of other bikes which have appeared in the show over the years.

Comment: “This year’s Christmas special The Snowmen (BBC 1, Christmas Day) features the Time Lord riding a bike” — I’m assuming this was a wrong guess on their part, as I’m pretty sure the bike appeared in *The Bells of St. John* (the first episode of season 7 part 2), and not the Victorian-set *The Snowmen*.

Answer (score 9):

Found it (I think): the Triumph Scrambler. Specifically that distinctive exhaust:

http://www.triumphmotorcycles.com/bikes/scrambler/2014/scrambler

Comment: Ooh, only 7 seconds too late.

Comment: Yeah, but my comment to the question was even earlier :) Still, what matters is not the first answer but the better answer and I believe alexwlchan has the better answer :D